# Android Studio set an OnClick paramenter in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I would like to know how I can add an OnClick method to a view in java, similarly to how you can setText or other set methods.

I want to do it in java since I am using  the array adapter to create them.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to provide us more code and context so we can help you with the problem.

Comment: `View::setOnClickListener()`? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Comment: you wan to a data from adapter using onClick in activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you give your view an id in the xml by adding this attribute to the view:

```
android:id="@+id/viewToClick"
```

Then you find that view in the Java code by (just like you would to by a setText):

```
View viewToClick = findViewById(R.id.viewToClick);
```

Finally you add the listener:

```
viewToClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Put your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have been able to research the answer on my own but as a beginner, I struggled, but this was the solution. Thanks!